# How to use the gRPC health probe in a container to check the health of a service running on the local machine?

Tags: docker, grpc

This question is similar to [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach), but since using `--network="host"` in the `docker run` command didn't work for me I'm asking the question again for my specific use case.

I have a Java gRPC server running locally on port 9095 which implements the [gRPC health checking protocol](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/health-checking.md):

```
> lsof -i :9095
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    17538 kurtpeek   89u  IPv6 0x14676dca7273b22d      0t0  TCP *:9095 (LISTEN)
```

I would like to verify that this is the case by using the [`grpc-health-probe`](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-health-probe). Since that repository only has releases for the Linux operating system but I'm running a Mac, I'd like to do this from a Docker container which is set up to forward requests to `localhost:9095` to the host machine.

Using this Dockerfile,

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install lsof wget
RUN GRPC_HEALTH_PROBE_VERSION=v0.3.6 && \
    wget -qO/bin/grpc_health_probe https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-health-probe/releases/download/${GRPC_HEALTH_PROBE_VERSION}/grpc_health_probe-linux-amd64 && \
    chmod +x /bin/grpc_health_probe
```

I built the image using `docker build --tag healthprobe .` and then ran it in interactive mode using the command

```
docker run -it --network="host" healthprobe bash
```

However, running `/bin/grpc_health_probe -addr=:9095` did not connect successfully with the local gRPC server, and `lsof` doesn't show that anything is listening on that port:

```
root@docker-desktop:/# /bin/grpc_health_probe -addr=:9095
timeout: failed to connect service ":9095" within 1s
root@docker-desktop:/# lsof -i :9095
root@docker-desktop:/#
```

Should using `--network="host"` not ensure that `lsof` gives me the same result as on my local machine? How can I get this container to probe the local health server?

Answer (score 1):

Why creating a new container to check health, why checking health in this scenario any way ?

Normally, grpc_health_probe is used to check health for a container in an orchestration environment like K8s. And you have to include the binary `grpc_health_probe` into your container and call it with localhost loopback in readiness or liveness probs like so :

```yaml
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/grpc_health_probe-linux-amd64", "-addr=localhost:50051"]
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 60
            timeoutSeconds: 30
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/grpc_health_probe-linux-amd64", "-addr=localhost:50051"]
            initialDelaySeconds: 20
            periodSeconds: 20
            timeoutSeconds: 30
```

Or with docker-compose as following :

```yaml
healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "bin/grpc_health_probe-linux-amd64", "-addr=localhost:50051"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a matter of running the docker container in privileged mode:

`docker run -it --network="host" --privileged healthprobe bash`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/#privileged